# How to run spotify in the background in 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, music, spotify

I'd installed Spotify via the snap command on Ubuntu 18.04. 
I want to run it in the background even if I close the window and control it via the system tray just how Rhythmbox works.
Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a small package called `kdocker`.

Install it via

```bsh
sudo apt install kdocker
```

Then launch Spotify or any other app and then launch `kdocker` and click on the Spotify screen. It will be docked and sent to background.

Answer (score 0):

You need 1st to update spotify. Open terminal and paste one by one the following lines:

```
 echo deb http://repository.spotify.com testing non-free | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list
sudo apt update
sudo apt-get install spotify-client
```

Then install missing tray with:

```
sudo apt install sni-qt
```

Then try either these commands:

```
spotify --minimized
```

OR

```
nohup spotify
```

you are done.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is `ncspot` which is a command line spotify client. It's really rather awesome and powerful.

You can get it from the snap store, or build it from source.

https://snapcraft.io/ncspot